# Display message(there is no data available) or empty graph for google pie chart if data is zero using asp.net web form

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

Display message(there is no data available) or empty graph for google pie chart if data is zero using asp.net web form

Below is my script

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    google.charts.load('current', { packages: ['corechart'] });
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {

        // Load the Visualization API and the corechart package.
        google.charts.load('current', { 'packages': ['corechart'] });
        // Set a callback to run when the Google Visualization API is loaded.
        google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
        // Callback that creates and populates a data table,
        // instantiates the pie chart, passes in the data and
        // draws it.
        function drawChart() {
            // Create the data table.
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "add_claim.aspx/Fillgraph",
                data: '{}',
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (r) {


                    if (r.d === null) {
                        document.getElementById('piechart').innerHTML = 'No data found.';
                        return;
                    }

                    var chartdata = new google.visualization.DataTable();
                    chartdata.addColumn('string', 'Topping');
                    chartdata.addColumn('number', 'Slices');

                    chartdata.addRows(r.d);


                    // Set chart options
                    var options = {
                        pieHole: 0.6,
                        legend: { position: 'bottom' },
                        width: '100%',
                        height: '100%',
                        pieSliceText: 'percentage',
                        colors: ['#1e93c6', '#d6563c', '#c79f49', '#ff9a00'],

                        chartArea: {
                            left: "3%",
                            top: "5%%",
                            height: "95%",
                            width: "94%"
                        }
                    };


                    var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('piechart'));
                    chart.draw(chartdata, options);


                },


                failure: function (r) {
                   // alert(r.d);
                },
                error: function (r) {
                  //  alert(r.d);
                }
            });
        }

    })
</script>
```

Below is my code behind c#

```
[WebMethod]
public static List<object> Fillgraph()
{
    BusinessLogic bl = new BusinessLogic();
    BusinessObject bo = new BusinessObject();
    List<object> chartData = new List<object>();

    bo.Para1 = "1";//@ParaValues

    bo.Para2 = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["UserId"].ToString();//@username
    bo.Para3 = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["UniqueID"].ToString();//@username

    DataTable dt = bl.ACS_Get_Graphs(bo);

    if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        if (dt.Rows[0]["Food"].ToString() != "")
        {
            chartData.Add(new object[] { "Food", Convert.ToInt32(dt.Rows[0]["Food"].ToString()) });
        }
        else
        {
            chartData.Add(new object[] { "Food", 0 });
        }
        if (dt.Rows[0]["LocalConveyance"].ToString() != "")
        {
            chartData.Add(new object[] { "Local conveyance", Convert.ToInt32(dt.Rows[0]["LocalConveyance"].ToString()) });
        }
        else
        {
            chartData.Add(new object[] { "Local conveyance", 0 });
        }
        if (dt.Rows[0]["Lodging"].ToString() != "")
        {
            chartData.Add(new object[] { "Lodging", Convert.ToInt32(dt.Rows[0]["Lodging"].ToString()) });
        }
        else
        {
            chartData.Add(new object[] { "Lodging", 0 });
        }
        if (dt.Rows[0]["MisExpences"].ToString() != "")
        {
            chartData.Add(new object[] { "Misc. Expences", Convert.ToInt32(dt.Rows[0]["MisExpences"].ToString()) });
        }
        else
        {
            chartData.Add(new object[] { "Misc. Expences", 0 });
        }

        if (dt.Rows[0]["Travelling"].ToString() != "")
        {
            chartData.Add(new object[] { "Travelling", Convert.ToInt32(dt.Rows[0]["Travelling"].ToString()) });
        }
        else
        {
            chartData.Add(new object[] { "Travelling", 0 });
        }

     return chartData;
    }
    else
    {
          return null;
    }


}
```

if Local conveyance=0 , Lodging=0  , Misc. Expences=0 and Travelling=0 then message should display there is no data availabe
or show empty pie graph

I tried below example but not able to getting

[How to display "No Data" message in the middle of chart area in column chart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38742523/how-to-display-no-data-message-in-the-middle-of-chart-area-in-column-chart)

[Google Charts - No data available - Able to display a blank chart?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26425187/google-charts-no-data-available-able-to-display-a-blank-chart)

JavaScript Debugger Image

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could return `null` from the WebMethod if there was no data

```
if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
{
    //rest of code
}
else
{
    return null;
}
```

Then check for null in the drawChart function at the top of `success: function (r)`

```
function drawChart() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "add_claim.aspx/Fillgraph",
        data: '{}',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (r) {

            if (r.d === null) {
                document.getElementById('piechart').innerHTML = 'No data found.';
                return;
            }

            var chartdata = new google.visualization.DataTable();
            chartdata.addColumn('string', 'Topping');
            chartdata.addColumn('number', 'Slices');       

            //rest of javascript code
```

Comment: can share you share full code because not working whatever you have given, i have debug and found into javascript, if (r.d === null) {  // r = {d: Array(5)} this value is coming from debug browse null is not showing 
                            document.getElementById('piechart').innerHTML = 'No data found.';
                            return;
                        }. @VVDWWD

Comment: The rest of the code is exactly the same as yours. I just replaced the 5 lines `chartData.Add(new object[] { "xxx", 0 });` in the `else` part with `return null` and added those 4 lines of javascript at the top inside the `success: function (r)`.  The `return` will ensure no chart code is executed.

Comment: I updated what you given question block please check question question once again, i am not getting any message. @VDWWD

Comment: I've updated my answer. You need to place the code in the first `success`. You seem to have multiple...

Comment: sorry by mistake i added bounty down side please how to add under your side and i not able to revert. @VDWWD

Comment: No problem. But weird that you cannot switch it... It's a known issue https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/310234/gave-bounty-to-wrong-answer-reversing-bounty

Answer (score 1):

The answers you have placed correspond to a LineChart, in your example you are using a PieChart, try replacing this:

**JS Code:**

```
// Instantiate and draw our chart, passing in some options.
var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('piechart'));
chart.draw(chartdata, options);
```

for this:

**JS Code:**

```
if (chartdata.getNumberOfRows() == 0) {

    var d = document.getElementById("piechart");

    d.innerHTML = "<p>Sorry, not info available</p>";

    // Custom style
    d.style.position = "relative";
    d.style.fontSize = "25px";

    d.style.right = "50%";
    d.style.left = "50%";

}
else {

    // Instantiate and draw our chart, passing in some options.
    var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('piechart'));
    chart.draw(chartdata, options);

}
```

*References:* [how to change the text 'no data' in google pie chart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27380516/how-to-change-the-text-no-data-in-google-pie-chart)

Comment: I tried your code again showing empty graph no message showing. @Julián

Comment: I have updated my answer, instead of `append` use `innerHTML`, do you use jQuery? if it doesn't work, could you publish your html code?

Comment: I added this also still getting empty. @Julián

Comment: do you have errors in the browser console? the div "piechart" is a simple div?

Comment: its going to else condition, Error is not showing in browse debugger. i think chartdata.getNumberOfRows() == 0 is not working correctly, as you given reference url that is different here i used   var chartdata = new google.visualization.DataTable(); and but reference url declaration is  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      ['Task', 'Hours per Day']

    ]);. @Julián